# SQL-PDO Connection, nothing displayed

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to connect to my sqldatabase using pdo. I've used
`PDO::getAvailableDrivers();` which returns mysql in the webpage.

I use:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=name', 'root', '');
```

to connect to my phpmyadmin. I am using Apache2 and Debian.

Please be aware that the dbname = name is the wrong databasename, I'm expecting
an error where it says "Cannot find the specific database" but instead the
page returns blank.

I've put in a wrong database name as a troubleshooting step, as the real one was not showing up either.

Am I missing something?

Comment: you'll get more visibility if you add a tag for php

Comment: A blank page when output is expected in PHP usually means you need to enable error reporting. Always when developing and testing, `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your script to identify a possible fatal error. PDO would issue a warning on failed connection.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin *is not* a database. It is a web interface for your MySQL database.